# angular 4 - reset template driven form validation after form submission

Tags: angular

My form opens like so:

```
<form novalidate #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="addPage(f)">
```

However, after successful submission I stay on the page and then validation messages pop up even though i don't want them to, so how do I reset form after submission?

The method that submits the form goes like so:

```
addPage({ value, valid }) {
```

I tried squeezing in `f` in there and then doing f.resetForm() but that didn't work out.

Comment: Can you provide fiddle demonstrating your issue?

Comment: are you calling reset in the addPage()  method?

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this (not sure where you tried to squeeze `f` in),

```
<form novalidate #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="addPage(f); f.resetForm()">
```

See if that worked. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There exists `form` property by default on which `reset()` can be called so it should be:

```
addPage({form, value, valid }) {
        form.reset();
        // rest of code
```